# How to get that my .exe does not stop in the middle of the night?

Tags: windows, server, exe

I have written a Telegram bot with the Telegram Bot API for C++. My bot itself uses the internet by the API itself and the urlmon.lib.

I run the .exe the whole time.
The program itself works fantastically but in the middle of the night it quits although it cannot be a bug as no statements were executed as the bot only operates when messages were sent in the corresponding Telegram chats.

I conclude that something needs to happen during the night and assume that the problem occurs after 4 A.M. as before messages are still sent by the bot.

My OS is Windows 10.
The aim is that the .exe of my Telegram bot runs the whole time without interruption.

Could it be that my Internet IP changes at that time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bypassed the problem with starting the exe after is was exited at 4:00am with this program: Windows Shutdown Assistant. It was suggested that the problem is caused by a DHCP Lease IP change.